# Does the Jacobian ring of a weighted projective hypersurface determine it up to isomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, projective-varieties

Let $V = H^0(\mathbb{P}^{n+1}, \mathcal{O}(1))$. Then the Mather-Yau Theorem states (Proposition 1.1 in *Generic Torelli for projective hypersurfaces*, Donagi)

> **Theorem.** If $f,g \in S^dV$ have the same Jacobian ideal, then they are related by an invertible projective transformation.

It's a corollary that (may need some assumptions on the degree of $X$ here, not sure at the moment)

> **Corollary.** Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ by a smooth hypersurface defined by a homogeneous polynomial $f$. Then the Jacobian ring $J(X) = \mathbb{C}[x_0, \dots, x_{n+1}] / (\partial_i f)$ determines $X$ up to isomorphism.

**Question:** Does the Mather-Yau Theorem hold in weighted projective space, and does the same corollary also hold in weighted projective space?

There is a notion of Jacobian ring for a hypersurface of weighted projective space, and in Donagi's paper, he states on p. 327 that the arguments to prove the main results of the paper (generic hypersurface Torelli) should go over without major change to the weighted projective setting. So I'm hoping that the Mather-Yau theorem and its corollary also go through without major change to weighted projective space. Is this true?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should look at "Macaulay's theorem and local Torelli for weighted hypersurfaces" by Tu, Compositio Mathematica, Volume 60 (1986) no. 1, p. 33-44. and also "Generic Torelli for Weighted Hypersurfaces" by Donagi and Tu, Math.Ann.276,399--413 (1987). The key difference is that Macaulay's theorem is generally false in the weighted case. In particular the (weighted) degree condition are much more restrictive than in the non-weighted case, and there are several counterexamples to infinitesimal Torelli known even in small dimension.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! These references are very useful. In particular, I see that in the second reference you give, Proposition 1.3 seems to be the weighted version of the theorem I stated in my question, and this doesn't seem to have any restriction on the degree. I guess this would mean that a corollary like the one in my question also follows for weighted hypersurfaces without restriction on the degree? I see that as you say, there are hard restrictions on the degree in these references, but I'm hoping that since I only require the corollary (and not the whole Torelli), I'm OK?